# updmap fails to create 10local.cfg

Tags: fonts, texlive, debian

i encountered a strange behaviour of **updmap** with texlive 2009-13:

When I try to enabe map files with updmap(-sys) (or run getnonfreefonts(-sys), the program exits silently.
Even with a complete new install.

It took me some time to work out why.

The problem occurs if the file /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10local.cfg does not exist already. The responsible line in the debianize-updmap file is:

```
localfile="`ls $debDirname/*local*cfg 2>/dev/null`"
```

The funny thing is, that with my old version everything was ok.
I guess the problem is the added line

```
set -e
```

which causes the script to exit if the ls does not find a file and thus returns exit code 2.

I wonder that i have not found anything about this in the internet yet.
Has anyone else encountered this problem, too?
Or knows any other solution? I temporary solved it for me by commenting out set -e.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug, but a (mis)feature of Debian.  Just say `touch /etc/texmf/updmap.d/10local.cfg`

Comment: Nice feature :) But i dont't understand why it was changed in updmap... But the 'solution' seems to be the best way to handle it. Thx!

Comment: Mh.. Now I have another problem with updmap. It does not run in --quiet mode. When i comment out the line "$verbose && echo ${1+"$@"} >&2" it works (Otherwise returns code 1). Any suggestions?

Comment: I always run it in the verbose mode...